# Using the :after CSS pseudo-element without inserting content

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Is it possible to use the `:after` CSS pseudo-element to offset alignment without actually inserting anything in `content: ""`. It doesn't seem to render unless content is specified so just wondered whether this is possible or if there are any known workarounds.

As an example:-

```
.nav-primary li.level0 a:after {
    content: "";
    padding-right: 1px;
    margin-left: -1px;
}
```

As you can see from the example, simply changing the colour of the content would not work in this instance as would still consume space affecting the offset.

Comment: No; content is required.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is possible to use an `:after` pseudo-element with the [`content` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#content) set to the empty string `""`, but not without setting it all (so that it has its initial value `none`, which means that the pseudo-element is not generated at all).

The reason why you do not see any effect is that your settings effectively cancel each other out. You set a negative left margin, shifting the element leftwards, but you set an equal amount of padding. The pseudo-element itself is empty and thus invisible, so all that matters is the space that it occupies.

This can be illustrated by drawing an outline. I’m using the value 10px instead of 1px for clarity:

```css
.nav-primary li.level0 a:after {
    content: "";
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    outline: solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class=nav-primary>
  <ul>
     <li class=level0><a href=foo>bar</a>xxx
     <li><a href=foo>bar</a>xxx
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

I ran into a similar situation which was fixed by adding `display: block` to the `:before` styles.

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge **it is possible** to use CSS pseudoelements with blank content. The attribute content needs to be specified but can be left blank (as you did in your example code).

I would think that your issue could be related to the display mode - pseudoelements are `inline` by default. If I understand well what you're trying to achieve, I would go this way:

- Set display mode to `inline-block`.
- Specify concrete dimensions of your offset alignment (width, height).

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rytc77ho/).